# Pubnub message receiveDate is nil when fetching messages on iOS

Tags: ios, pubnub

When fetching messages from [Pubnub](https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c), its `receiveDate` is nil. Here's an example attached on what I'm doing:

```
void (^completionBlock)(NSArray *pnMessages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) = ^(NSArray *pnMessages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {
for (PNMessage *pnMessage in pnMessages) {
    NSDate *date = pnMessage.receiveDate; // <-- date here is nil (pnMessage.date also)

    // some logic here with date.
}

// fetch messages.
[PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:_channel withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
```

Any ideas something else has to be done to retrieve the date for each message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use appropriate methods to make sure those values to be filled. By default **PubNub** service won't provide this information to you and you have to use specific methods like this one (there is other designated methods):

```
+ (void)requestFullHistoryForChannel:(PNChannel *)channel 
                  includingTimeToken:(BOOL)shouldIncludeTimeToken
                 withCompletionBlock:(PNClientHistoryLoadHandlingBlock)handleBlock
```

This method explicitly request **PubNub** service to return date when this message has been delivered from client to the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

First step: Send your PubNub message in a dictionary format. You can add a `key` that holds the date when you send the message.

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                           @"sender":senderSample,
                           @"message":messageSample;
                           @"date":dateString;
                           };

[PubNub sendMessage: dictionary toChannel:sampleChannel];
```

Second step: Retrieve messages, and now you have messages with date.

```
[PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel: sampleChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error)

   NSLog(@"Here's my new messages with date %@", message);


}];
```

If you run your app and check the console you will see the `message` array, that contains `PNMessage` objects. Now you have to work with the `message` property (which contains the `date key`) instead of the `receiveDate`. Every new message object will contains the date you can use.